# Docker - Nginx, PHP, MongoDB - Laravel artisan migrate connection timeout

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, docker

I have Laravel running in Docker with 6 containers - Nginx, MongoDB, PHP, Composer, Npm and Artisan.

Here is my docker-compose-yaml :

```yaml
version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:

services:

  site:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx.dockerfile
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mongodb
    networks:
      - laravel
    
  mongodb:
    image : mongo:latest
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes: 
      - /data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    environment:
      PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR: "/usr/local/etc/php/custom.d:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d"
    networks:
      - laravel

  composer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: composer.dockerfile
    container_name: composer
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - php
    user: laravel
    entrypoint: ['composer', '--ignore-platform-reqs']
    networks:
      - laravel

  npm:
    image: node:13.7
    container_name: npm
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['npm']
    networks:
      - laravel

  artisan:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    container_name: artisan
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    user: laravel
    entrypoint: ['php', '/var/www/html/artisan']
    networks:
      - laravel
```

Here is my Laravel database config :

```php
'mongodb' => [
        'driver' => 'mongodb',
        'host' => 'mongodb',
        'port' => 27017,
        'database' => env('MONGO_DB_DATABASE'),
        'username' => env('MONGO_DB_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('MONGO_DB_PASSWORD'),
        'options' => [
            'database' => env('MONGO_DB_DATABASE') // sets the authentication database required by mongo 3
        ]
    ],
```

And here is my mongodb part in the .env file :

```php
MONGO_DB_DATABASE=mongolara
MONGO_DB_USERNAME=
MONGO_DB_PASSWORD=
```

I want to run php artisan migrate, so I run this :

```sh
sudo docker-compose run --rm artisan migrate
```

But it give me this error :

```sh
MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException 
No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [Failed to resolve 'mongodb']
```

I've tried changing some configs like ports, host, .. but the error is still here. Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: If you use mongodb as database, you don't need to run artisan:migrate

Comment: In fact, I want to launch migrations to create my User table, and then be able to register my users as I want, how could I do that without using migrations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has two solutions to that:

1. Put the service `mongodb` on the same network of the others services.
2. To use the exposed port on host, in to laravel configuration, do you need put `0.0.0.0` the host of mongodb.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had indeed forgotten to put MongoDB on the same network as my other services. I also tested the second solution which works just as well.